# How to convert wstring to char array or compare using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I tried different way, but it seems not working. Please help me.

```
    wstring strname  =  "C:\\Users\\projects\\app.exe";
    char processName[] = "newapp.exe";
```

I  have to get **app.exe** from strname and compare that against processName(newapp.exe)

Comment: Presumably neither of these are literals in the real code.

Comment: ok, I will add my actual code.I am looking for any API which returns the name if I pass the file path including the name,

Comment: @JChan : [`PathFindFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: `PathFindFileName` is an excellent start. All that remains is to convert `processName` to be a Unicode string. Is your app targeting ANSI or Unicode? Why do you have `processName` as a `char[]` rather than a `wstring`?

Comment: @ilsjarm,@David Heffernman.. thanks ,  I am targetting unicode, I couldn't convert TCHAR* to char[], so made it as wstring.

Comment: where is your char[] coming from? Why don't you use wchar_t[]?

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract file name from `strname` using `_wsplitpath` and store it in another wstring.
2. Use `MultiByteToWideChar` or `mbstowcs` to convert `processName` to wide-character string.
3. Compare.